# how to get data from google sheets API in nested format in json

Tags: json, google-sheets

I am trying to create a chart with  live data and it is changing.The issue is the rows are in group there kind of nested format like this:

[image: Screen shot of my google sheet]

now when I am getting data from api I am not getting this nested stucture in json. instead I am getting plan value one after other.. is there any way to fix it..?
This is my google sheets link

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RnaNprI_CR4U8be4B_-NX7gk6OJUQA1IIetnYPR6NW0/edit#gid=1253029974
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `now when I am getting data from api I am not getting this nested stucture in json. instead I am getting plan value one after other.. is there any way to fix it..?`. In order to correctly understand your question, can I ask you about the sample output you expect from your sample Spreadsheet? And also, can I ask you about the language you want to use?

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow community. Please, consider reading this before posting a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As @Tanaike says, it would be helpful if you provide some context to your question. In any case, the format of the response usually is [ValueRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#resource:-valuerange), is that what you mean?

Comment: You wrote, *now when I am getting data from api I am not getting this nested stucture in json. instead I am getting plan value one after other..* -- then please [edit] your question with a [mcve] showing **your current code** that gets data from the API in the wrong format.  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*  As it is you haven't included the code which isn't working properly, so your question may get closed as "Needs Debugging Details."